# Reverse Words in a String III java runtime error

Tags: java

I keep getting a run time error of index out of bounds. Can you spot where I went wrong? Or is my solution wrong

question to solve: Given a string, you need to reverse the order of characters in each word within a sentence while still preserving whitespace and initial word order.

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {

        String ret = "";
        String temp = "";
        int start = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){     
            if( !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) ){
                temp += s.charAt(i);
            }
            else if(i == s.length()-1){
                ret += rev(temp,start,i);
            }
            else{   
                ret += rev(temp,start,i-1) + s.charAt(i);
                start = i+1;
                temp = "";

            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public String rev(String word, int start, int end){

        char[] input = word.toCharArray();

        while(start < end){
            char temp = input[start];
            input[start] = input[end];
            input[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        return input.toString();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that HankerRank I see >:D. Can you show the exception?

Comment: This kind of questions is what debuggers are for. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What input that was provided caused the exception?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 4

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sending me a link is not going to help solve this problem.If that. was the case I would have posted this question.

Comment: Sure it does! It teaches you that before asking a question you should show that you tried by yourself. If I thought that you *did* try debugging first I wouldn't have given you that link.